# Rails 4 Foundation Import Doesnt' Seem To Work

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

I have recently upgraded my application from Rails 3.2.13 and Ruby 1.9.3 to Rails 4.0.0rc1 and Ruby 2.0.0. All working okay, except Foundation doesn't seem to be working. The application seems to load the foundation_and_overrides.scss because my custom css added to the bottom of the file seems to be loaded and working. All of the foundation styles don't load, it looks like a an application with no css.

[image: See Image]

Any help or advice on diagnosing this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Lee

Application html:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

Application.css

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require foundation_and_overrides

 *= require_tree .
*/
```

foundation_and_overrides.scss

```
@import 'foundation';
```

Comment: Can you post your css file and your application.css file or wherever you are importing your foundation styles

Comment: Added the basics for you

Comment: You are using gem for foundation?

Comment: @Mandeep Yes using the gem foundation-rails 5.4.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by updating the version of sass-rails gem from 4.0.0 to 4.0.3. Seems that version didn't like Foundation.